# how to use state value in makeStyles in materail ui react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am creating a `Webpage`. I am using `Material UI` for Components.
Here's the Code:

```
import {  makeStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

    container: {
        backgroundColor: "white", display: displayStyle
    },

}));
export default function HomePage() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [displayStyle, setDisplayStyle] = useState("flex")

    return (
        <>
            <div>My Page</div>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <div >
                    <Typography  >
                        Our Orders
                    </Typography>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

I have a state named `displayStyle` . I want to use this state value in `makeStyles`. But it shows `displayStyle` is undefined because it is inside the Function. How to make it use in `makeStyles`. I want to set `Styles` based on the `state` value. Please help me with some solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state` is available in the component. So you need to move `useStyles` into your component to access the `displayStyle`:

```
import {  makeStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
export default function HomePage() {
    const [displayStyle, setDisplayStyle] = useState("flex")
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        container: {
            backgroundColor: "white", display: displayStyle
        },
    }));
    const classes = useStyles();

   
    return (
        <>
            <div>My Page</div>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <div >
                    <Typography  >
                        Our Orders
                    </Typography>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Solution is to move makeStyles in the component and if you don't want to move it in the component then you can try this hack

```
import {  makeStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

let style;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

    container: {
        backgroundColor: "white", display: style
    },

}));
export default function HomePage() {
    const [displayStyle, setDisplayStyle] = useState("flex")
    style = displayStyle;
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <>
            <div>My Page</div>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <div >
                    <Typography  >
                        Our Orders
                    </Typography>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why to add another variable named `style`, just simply make the state `displayStyle` in the scope of `useStyle function`?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply make the `displayStyle` available to `useStyle function` by defining the state in the `useStyle` function.

Move this line inside the `useStyle` function.

```
const [displayStyle, setDisplayStyle] = useState("flex");
```

So our component looks like this

```
import {  makeStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

    const [displayStyle, setDisplayStyle] = useState("flex")

    container: {
        backgroundColor: "white", display: displayStyle
    },

}));
export default function HomePage() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <>
            <div>My Page</div>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <div >
                    <Typography  >
                        Our Orders
                    </Typography>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```